# How to add a User Control in a div at a particular position?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have a div

```
<div id="PageContent" runat="server"></div>
```

I am adding some HTML to it from code behind like this

```
PageContent.InnerHtml ="<p> this is my text</p>";
```

Now how can i add a User Control from code behind between *my* and *text* and can i also replace my and add User Control at that position?

I don't want to use any placeholder or panel in PageContent div.

Comment: Create your own custom control accepts `template string` and call `.Render()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
public string RenderControlToHtml(Control ControlToRender)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            System.IO.StringWriter stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
            ControlToRender.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        var message = "<p>this is my {0} text</p>";

        var ctrl1 = new UserControl1();

        PageContent.InnerHtml = String.Format(message,RenderControlToHtml(ctrl1));
```

You also need to add

```
public override bool EnableEventValidation
        {
            get { return false; }
            set { /* Do nothing */}
        }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        { /* Do nothing */ }
```

In order to render User Control from Code behind

Answer (score -1):

You may use two different div to do.

Eg:

```
<div id="PageContentBegin" runat="server"></div>

<ucl id="UserControlId" runat="server" Visible="False"></ucl>

<div id="PageContentEnd" runat="server"></div>


PageContentBegin.InnerHtml ="<p> this is my </p>";
UserControlId.Visible = True
PageContentBegin.InnerHtml ="<p>  text </p>";
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. It avoids the issue of 'injecting' the user control into other markup into one div. Feels a bit like a workaround using two divs to split the markup out. What if the user control were to not be displayed there? You'd have '<p> this is my' in one div and ' text </p>', for example, in the other, which makes little sense.

Comment: I want to add user control in the given div at a particular position and i'm adding user control from code behind after providing HTML to div.